# keep one half of the custom view outside the screen in android

Tags: android

I have created a custom view in android. Its like circle and I want to keep one half of it outside the screen . How can I achieve this? Actually I am using it in sliding drawer. I have used android:layout_weight but did not succeed. Any help would be appreciated.
If its possible to limit the width of sliding drawer when it opens? it would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: align it with parent left or right then specify the margin from left or right in -dp, like android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"

Comment: I should give it a try. I will let you know what happens

Comment: @Astral can I limit the opening width of sliding drawer? If yes, then how ?

Comment: You very well can, check `offset` Google it!